# Where it has been written that a particular Vedic hymn has to be associated with a specific devata, rishi, etc

Tags: vedas

We all maintain that each Vedic hymn is associated with a devata, Chanda, and rishi as maintained in Anukraminika. But what is the source of our that belief? Where it has been written that verse has to be associated with a devata, Chanda & rishi? Is there specific verse from scripture that's revealing the fact?

Answer (score 4):

Each mantra was revealed by a specific rishi, composed in a particular poetic meter and dedicated to one or more deities. As the Veda is a collection of mantras passed down from the time of the rishis, these attributes (devatA, RShi, chandas) have been an inseparable part of each mantra.

Niruktam (7.1-3):

> यत्काम ऋषिर्यस्यां देवतायामार्थपत्यमिच्छन्स्तुतिं प्रयुङ्क्ते तद् दैवतः स मन्त्रो भवति 
>  The mantra belongs to the deity who is eulogized by the rishi with a specific desire that the deity can fulfill.

Comment: welcome to the [Hinduism forum](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)  For the benefit of everyone we suggest answers that are backed up by [references to scriptures](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/3294). Can you please add [some reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/40759/edit) to your statements?

Comment: Sir I really have a doubt. <<specific desire that the deity can fulfill>>
But Gita and Upanishads ask us to be free from desires..Don't they?

Answer (score 3):

For the deity, the formula given in **Nirukta 7:4** is provided.

> “The stanzas whose deity is not specified, such **stanzas belong to the same deity to whom that particular sacrifice, or a part of the sacrifice, is offered**. Now, elsewhere than the sacrifice, they belong to Prajapati according to the ritualists; and to Narasamsa according to the etymologists.”

Comment: Can you give me a little more information about Nirukta? Is this a Shruti scripture?

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Yes. It is a Vedanga. Read this[1]:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.hinduwebsite.com/hinduism/concepts/vedangas.asp&ved=2ahUKEwid7tGAvrXpAhVQyjgGHevdC6UQFjAeegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2QpOUkf5PyvHLQrCTB5IAC